# How to create a change log for all tables in mySQL?

Tags: mysql

I saw a few solutions here for creating a change log but I want a solution for all the tables in my database. For example, in my database there are

```
TABLE: accounts

id     name     address    email     password

TABLE: customer_1

transaction_id     products      total_amount


TABLE: customer_2

transaction_id     products      total_amount

TABLE: subscriptions

sl  user_id  email   paid_amount   valid_till
```

As you can see I have a table for each customer, along with master accounts table, subscription table etc. Each table has different columns too. What I need is a changelog for all the tables. Like this

```
TABLE: changelog

sl     table      action        datetime             particulars
1    accounts      update    2022-03-03 14:30:00    changed name from "John" to "John Keller", changed address from "NY" to "TX"
2    customer_2    insert    2022-03-03 14:35:00    transaction_id=5, products="[1,2,3]", total_amount=100
```

So I can get all the data that is changed, inserted or deleted in a single table. IS this possible?

Comment: I think you can try to use trigger

Comment: Please write an answer @D-Shih